Cannot locate cell content using Selenium and BeautifulSoup
New to web scraping and selenium/beautifulsoup in general. I've been trying to scrape data from this website but beautifulsoup can't seem to find the text that I want. I just want the date of the first incident that shows up so I used inspect element to find the text is in a vaadin-grid-cell-content tag with slot="vaadin-grid-cell-content-10"
I tried commands like driver.find_element using xpath and .find with beautifulsoup but can't seem to find the element. I'm currently using a driver to access the website.
driver.get("https://data.ntsb.gov/carol-main-public/query-builder?month=6&year=2024")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

element = soup.find('vaadin-grid-cell-content', {'slot': 'vaadin-grid-cell-content-10'})
date_text = element.text.strip()
print(date_text)

driver.quit()


why use selenium when you can scrape their api?

Based on the one time I've used Beautiful Soup, I found it helpful to iterate over and print all the elements that it finds. This approach allowed me to know exactly what thing to access to get what I needed. Maybe this approach can help you.

You can try to use their Ajax API to get the data, e.g.:
import random

import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url = "https://data.ntsb.gov/carol-main-public/api/Query/Main"

payload = {
    "AndOr": "and",
    "QueryGroups": [
        {
            "AndOr": "and",
            "editedSinceLastSearch": False,
            "inLastSearch": False,
            "QueryRules": [
                {
                    "Columns": ["Event.EventDate"],
                    "Operator": "is on or after",
                    "overrideColumn": "",
                    "RuleType": "Simple",
                    "selectedOption": {
                        "Columns": ["Event.EventDate"],
                        "DisplayText": "Event date",
                        "FieldName": "EventDate",
                        "InputType": "Date",
                        "Options": None,
                        "RuleType": 0,
                        "Selectable": True,
                        "TargetCollection": "cases",
                        "UnderDevelopment": True,
                    },
                    "Values": ["2024-06-01"],
                },
                {
                    "Columns": ["Event.EventDate"],
                    "Operator": "is on or before",
                    "overrideColumn": "",
                    "RuleType": "Simple",
                    "selectedOption": {
                        "Columns": ["Event.EventDate"],
                        "DisplayText": "Event date",
                        "FieldName": "EventDate",
                        "InputType": "Date",
                        "Options": None,
                        "RuleType": 0,
                        "Selectable": True,
                        "TargetCollection": "cases",
                        "UnderDevelopment": True,
                    },
                    "Values": ["2024-06-30"],
                },
                {
                    "Columns": ["Event.Mode"],
                    "Operator": "is",
                    "overrideColumn": "",
                    "RuleType": "Simple",
                    "selectedOption": {
                        "Columns": ["Event.Mode"],
                        "DisplayText": "Investigation mode",
                        "FieldName": "Mode",
                        "InputType": "Dropdown",
                        "Options": None,
                        "RuleType": 0,
                        "Selectable": True,
                        "TargetCollection": "cases",
                        "UnderDevelopment": True,
                    },
                    "Values": ["Aviation"],
                },
            ],
        }
    ],
    "ResultSetOffset": 0,
    "ResultSetSize": 50,
    "SessionId": random.randint(100_000, 200_000),
    "SortColumn": None,
    "SortDescending": True,
    "TargetCollection": "cases",
}

headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}

data = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json=payload).json()

all_data = []
for r in data["Results"]:
    all_data.append(
        {f["FieldName"]: f["Values"][-1] if f["Values"] else None for f in r["Fields"]}
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df.head())

Prints:
       NtsbNo CompletionStatus EventType    Mkey IsStudy             EventDate                       City           State        Country ReportNo      N#                     VehicleMake VehicleModel HighestInjuryLevel HasSafetyRec      Mode     ReportType DocketPublishDate OriginalPublishedDate                ReportDate MostRecentReportType EV_ID RepGenFlag
0  WPR24LA206          In work  Accident  194538   false  2024-06-23T20:42:00Z                    Spokane      Washington  United States     None  N4059D                          Cessna         182A               None        false  Aviation  DirectorBrief              None                  None  2024-06-25T01:15:46.264Z                 None  None       None
1  ANC24LA053          In work  Accident  194525   false  2024-06-23T19:00:00Z                        Tok          Alaska  United States     None  N2839C                          Cessna         170B               None        false  Aviation  DirectorBrief              None                  None  2024-06-25T20:35:32.888Z                 None  None       None
2  ERA24LA273          In work  Accident  194534   false  2024-06-23T15:00:00Z                    Laurens  South Carolina  United States     None   N60DF  CONSTRUZIONI AERONAUTICHE TECN  P2004 BRAVO               None        false  Aviation  DirectorBrief              None                  None  2024-06-25T20:45:39.916Z               Prelim  None       None
3  CEN24LA238          In work  Accident  194533   false  2024-06-23T10:50:00Z           FORT LEAVENWORTH          Kansas  United States     None   N74CF                          Cessna        A185F               None        false  Aviation  DirectorBrief              None                  None   2024-06-24T23:00:38.74Z                 None  None       None
4  WPR24LA209          In work  Accident  194541   false  2024-06-22T13:00:00Z  Chamberlain Guard Station           Idaho  United States     None  N4722B                          Cessna          180               None        false  Aviation  DirectorBrief              None                  None  2024-06-25T01:30:53.825Z                 None  None       None

